# Restrict jQuery Datepicker for this full year and Next year's first date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How to Restrict jQuery Datepicker to show only this full year and Next year's first date

For e.g:

i want result something like this `02-01-2014` to `01-01-2015` (date in dd-mm-yyyy) format.

I've tried it far:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: '-0:+0'
    });
```

Comment: Just to make this perfectly clear, you want the user to only be able to select any date from the 2nd of January of the current year (e.g. 2nd January 2014 this year) to the 1st of January of the following year?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, i want that only :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :)

```
    var t = new Date();
    t.setFullYear(t.getFullYear(), 11, 32);
    var max_date = t.getDate() + '-' + (t.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + t.getFullYear();

    t.setFullYear(( t.getFullYear() - 2), 11, 33);
    var min_date = t.getDate() + '-' + (t.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + t.getFullYear();

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: min_date,
        maxDate: max_date
    });
```

I hope this is right solution